# sparse matrix transpose in scipy

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix

I initialized my sparse matrix like this:

```
from scipy.sparse import lil_matrix
import numpy as np

X = [lil_matrix((3,3)) for i in range(2)]
X[0][0,0]=1
X[1][0,0]=1
X[1][0,1]=1
```

I transposed this matrix like this:

```
elem =[a.toarray() for a in X]
elem =np.array(elem)
new_mat = np.array(elem.reshape((3,3,2)))
T = [lil_matrix(new_mat[:, :, i]) for i in range(new_mat.shape[2])]
```

As in my case my `X` sparse matrix is quite huge and while converting X to T this way I encountered memory error. Is there an efficient way to do this?

Comment: `X` is not a sparse matrix, it is a *list*.

Comment: Of course you get into trouble, as you cast your sparse matrix into a normal one. Why not to use the transpose function for one of your matrices, e.g., `X[0].transpose()`?

Comment: So `elem` is a `(2,3,3)` dense array.  Do you just want to reshape it, or transpose it?   In the big array case you may have to create a blank `T`, and copy nonzero values from `X`.  Your 'transpose' is non-standard, and will require a custom solution.

Answer (score 1):

Make your array (with different dimensions to highlight the transpose ambiguity):

```
In [859]: X=[sparse.lil_matrix((3,4)) for i in range(2)]
In [860]: X
Out[860]: 
[<3x4 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 0 stored elements in LInked List format>,
 <3x4 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 0 stored elements in LInked List format>]
In [861]: X[0][0,0]=1
In [862]: X[1][0,0]=1
In [864]: X[1][0,1]=1
```

Now the raw data for this list of matrices is:

```
In [866]: X[0].rows
Out[866]: array([[0], [], []], dtype=object)
In [867]: X[0].data
Out[867]: array([[1.0], [], []], dtype=object)
In [868]: X[1].rows
Out[868]: array([[0, 1], [], []], dtype=object)
In [869]: X[1].data
Out[869]: array([[1.0, 1.0], [], []], dtype=object)
```

If I make a 3d array from `X`:

```
In [870]: elem = np.array([a.A for a in X])
In [871]: elem
Out[871]: 
array([[[ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]],

       [[ 1.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]]])
```

The proper transpose of this 3d is a (4,3,2) array:

```
In [872]: elem.T
Out[872]: 
array([[[ 1.,  1.],
        [ 0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.]],

       [[ 0.,  1.],
        [ 0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.]],

       [[ 0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.]],

       [[ 0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.]]])
```

reshaping can be done, but tends to shuffle values around:

```
In [873]: elem.reshape(3,4,2)
Out[873]: 
array([[[ 1.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.]],

       [[ 0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.],
        [ 1.,  1.],
        [ 0.,  0.]],

       [[ 0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.]]])
```

In any case, if `X` is so big that `elem` gives memory error, I think your only alternative is to make a new blank `X1` list (e.g. 4 matrices of shape (3,2)), and copy values from the original matrices.  For a start I'd try to use the `lil` attributes I list above, but it's possible that one of the other formats is more convenient.  `sparse` code often uses the `coo` format construct a new matrix from smaller ones (e.g look at the `sparse.bmat` code).

For something as non-standard as this, I doubt if there's any easy stock solution.  We don't normally mix and match elements of a list of sparse matrices.